# Error when using Decision Trees in OpenCV 3.0.0-rc1

Tags: c++, opencv, segmentation-fault, decision-tree, bad-alloc

I am doing some machine learning in OpenCV and i'm using **Decision Trees**. I am currently using **OpenCV 3.0.0-rc1**. Whenever i attempt to train Decision Trees with my training data and labels, i get either

> terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
>    what():  std::bad_alloc

or

> Segmentation fault

Depending on what i put into setMaxDepth(); if the number is larger than 22, it's bad_alloc, else it's seg fault. 
Here's my source code:

```
//import data
Mat trainData=imread("/home/jetson/Documents/CB/ml/td.jpg",CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
Mat labels=imread("/home/jetson/Documents/CB/ml/lab.jpg",CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
//convert to the right type
trainData.convertTo(trainData,CV_32FC1);
labels.convertTo(labels,CV_32SC1);
transpose(trainData,trainData);
Ptr<ml::TrainData> tData = ml::TrainData::create(trainData, ml::ROW_SAMPLE, labels);

cout <<"Training data ready\n";

Ptr<ml::DTrees> dec_trees = ml::DTrees::create();
//params
dec_trees->setMaxDepth(1);
dec_trees->setMinSampleCount(10);
dec_trees->setRegressionAccuracy(0.01f);
dec_trees->setUseSurrogates(false);
dec_trees->setMaxCategories(2);
dec_trees->setCVFolds(10);
dec_trees->setUse1SERule(true);
dec_trees->setTruncatePrunedTree(true);
dec_trees->setPriors(Mat());

cout <<"Params set\n";
dec_trees->train(tData);
cout <<"Done!\n";`
```

In addition to this, when i try to train a SVM model with the same data, using the same steps (below) it works just fine.

```
Ptr<ml::SVM> svm = ml::SVM::create();
//params
svm->setType(ml::SVM::C_SVC);
svm->setKernel(ml::SVM::POLY);
svm->setGamma(3);
svm->setDegree(0.1);

cout <<"Params set\n";
svm->train(tData);
cout <<"Done!\n";
```

I need to point out that the error occurs when i try to train the model. I'm using the default parameters for decision trees, as suggested on the OpenCV documentation page. 
Does anybody know what's wrong here and how to go about fixing my problem?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I upgraded OpenCV to version 3.0.0 and the issues stay the same

Comment: Here I guess u are doing classification. I am new to Opencv. Can u tell what we will will put in the place of the setMaxCategories in case we are doing regression